# File handling in Java - User Rights

Tags: java, file-handling

Can someone tell me how can I get file write permissions when handling text files in Java, so that my program can write on any computer hard drive. As the file path common in Windows os for any PC is C:\Windows or C:\Users etc. I want to write data on such type of location without getting a restriction from the administrator.

Comment: That is *not possible* without giving a password. If this was possible, then it would be a **huge** security hole.

Comment: Actually the scenario is that I have developed a java GUI program that is like a student report card and stores data in a text file. This text file will be saved at some location like C:\etc...I want other people to run this program on their PCs. The problem is that I don't know how to give my program access to their hard drive .? I am getting an access denied message when I try to do this using the FileWriter even on my own PC.

Comment: you need to choose a directory to which your user has the rights to write files.  it's that simple.